# Can someone explain the reorder_queue_size option of rtsp input in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I can't find any information about it except one sentence in documentation - Set number of packets to buffer for handling of reordered packets.
Can it help with unstable network or stream? What default value is and what value should be set and when?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packets may be received out of order, so before they can be passed onwards, they need to be reordered. Default jitter buffer size is 500. This option allows you to specify it manually. Higher values will lead to greater latency. Only applicable for reception over UDP.

Comment: What happens if number of packets with wrong order is more than this queue size?

Comment: @albert200000 The packet will be considered as lost, so the slices contained in it will be lost, too, and have to be concealed while decoding.

Comment: Where is documented that the `jitter buffer size` is "500"? I'm looking in the docs (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html) and it doesn't seem to mention the default value. (And thanks for your answer, that seems to make sense.)

Comment: Just confirmed for you. When I set `-loglevel verbose` I see a message upon connecting to the RTSP stream that says `setting jitter buffer size to 500`. And then when setting `-reorder_queue_size 10000`, this log message becomes `setting jitter buffer size to 10000`. So there ya go.

Comment: I'd like to add here that `-reorder_queue_size` interplays greatly with `-max_delay` so you'll want to look at that as well. As your `-reorder_queue_size` increases, so must your `-max_delay` in order to allow for a longer time to receive packets and then reorder them. Otherwise, you will get `max delayed reached`.